# I want to perform a rest api request on click of a button angular js

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, angular-material

I want to perform a rest api on click of a button and show a loading bar until the request is completed and show the result of request in a mddialog . I am new to this I dont know how to proceed.

Any answers help would be appreciated.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url1
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
      .title('Download as CSV')
      .textContent('You can download the csv by clicking below link')
      .ariaLabel('Download')
      .targetEvent(response.data.export_url)
      .ok('Download as CSV');
    $mdDialog.show(confirm);
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: Following the tags, you are using AngularJS so could you please provide us your code / what you tried ?

Answer (score 2):

**Your click action**

```
<input type="button" ng-click="performCall()" />
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.performCall = function(){
    // Simple GET request example:
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/someUrl'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
       // this callback will be called asynchronously
       // when the response is available
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
       // called asynchronously if an error occurs
       // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
}
```

**The loading bar**

You just need to install this 
[Angular loader](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/) and it will do the rest for you

Comment: What do you mean ? A button on the dialog ? The button that calls the api performCall method ?

Comment: This is my code i want href on ok of dialog             $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url1
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response.data.export_url);
    var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
      .title('Download as CSV')
      .textContent('You can download the csv by clicking below link')
      .ariaLabel('Download')
      .targetEvent(ev)
      .ok('Download as CSV');
    $mdDialog.show(confirm);

Comment: I dont know how this kind of dialog works sorry... Anyway you used my answer to edit your question. Could you please give me the credits