# How to call API on click of button in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have all Java files and have some API which want to call on the click of the button to post data in DB.I dont know how to call those API in Angular JS

I have tried using postman.It is done

Comment: I want to get the same thing done with angular JS and not with Postman

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396552/i-want-to-perform-a-rest-api-request-on-click-of-a-button-angular-js

Comment: Hey, Have you looked at their [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) ?

Comment: Please post angular files what you have

Answer (score 0):

You just need place $http service to component/service as dependency and then call something like this

```
$http.get('phones/phones.json').then(function(response) {
   console.log(response.data);
});
```

Check this manual https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs has $http service so you can do like this:

Your html:

```
<input type='text', ng-model='user.username' />
<button ng-click='hitApi(user)'>Hit</button>
```

Your controller:

```
$scope.user = {}; // in this object you are binding your data.

const hitApi = (data) => {
  $http.post('url', data)
  // send that data to backend using post method
   .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to use `fetch` instead.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <button ng-click="callAPI()">OK</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.myFunc = function() {
                fetch(url)
                .then((resp) => resp.json())
                .then(function(data) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                });
            };
        }]);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: why you are using fetch method instead of angularjs default $http service?

Comment: i hate that extra .then in fetch.

Comment: main concern is sometimes, `$http` can't be able to fetch `header` value from `response`. For `fetch` it's kinda easy to do so `response.headers.get('jwt-token')`.